# Need help mysql joining table

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables and want to join it

**student**

```
id   student_name   angkatan

s_1  yan            a_1
s_2  teo            a_1
s_3  mirna          a_2
```

**angkatan**

```
id  angkatan   name

a_1 angkatan   1
a_2 angkatan   2
```

**sub**

```
id     sub_name  payment

sub_1  bag       1000
sub_2  book      2000
```

**resume**

```
id   angkatan    sub
1    a_1         sub_1
2    a_1         sub_2
3    a_2         sub_2
```

from resume table i want to the new table has result like this
if in table resume it says angkatan = ang_1 it will select all student with angkatan = ang_1 with sub

```
nim name   angkatan  sub
s_1 iyan   a_1       bag
s_2 teo    a_1       bag
s_1 iyan   a_1       book
s_2 teo    a_1       book
s_3 mirna  a_2       book
```

how to do that? i trying but still couldnot found how

thanks for help

Comment: can you attach what have you tried so far?

Comment: wait, i trying join student with angkatan and sub with resume

Comment: SELECT sub_bayar.kode, sub_bayar.nama, sub_bayar.tagihan,sub_bayar.tagihan
FROM sub_bayar
INNER JOIN resume_sub ON sub_bayar.kode = resume_sub.kode

and also mahasiswa and angkatan but cant know how to join 4 table

Comment: The table names in your query don't match the table definitions in your post. We can help you, but please be clear with your database schema and your query. For example, you have a table definition for `sub` but in your query you call it `sub_bayar` ?

Comment: @riyantonugroho if I am not mistaken, you want to show get all studen name and his sub_name based on angkatan type,am I correct?

Comment: thx mat and gusti arya iam trying combining resume_sub and student and get exactly what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the tables and their values shared above, the query to obtain the required results for `angkatan = 'a_1'` will look like

```
SELECT      STU.ID AS NIM, 
            STU.STUDENT_NAME AS NAME, 
            STU.ANGKATAN, 
            SUB.SUB_NAME AS SUB 
FROM        STUDENT STU 
LEFT JOIN   ANGKATAN ANG
ON          STU.ANGKATAN = ANG.ID
LEFT JOIN   RESUME RES
ON          RES.ANGKATAN = ANG.ID
LEFT JOIN   SUB SUB
ON          RES.SUB = SUB.ID
WHERE       RES.ANGKATAN = 'a_1'
ORDER BY    STU.ID
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If the answer has helped you resolve the problem, you should accept (click the `tick` sign) the answer according to the SO guidelines.